# regex to strip out [blah: ... ] tag from string

Tags: c#, regex

I am using this regex:

```
[Blah(?:\s*)\]
```

I want to strip out the tag that looks like:

```
[Blah:http:..anyting goes here so catch all types of characters ]
```

Any tips on what's wrong with my regex?

Comment: are you just trying to capture the http:\\ vs https:\\ ~ if so I might have a different way.

Comment: no, i don't want to capture, remove the entire tag. not capturing anything.

Comment: is it because you are not escaping the opening square bracket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regex of `\[Blah[^\]]*\]` is the usual way.  It means:

- literal string `[Blah`
- zero or more:

  - characters that aren't `]`
- literal string `]`

If you want to handle nesting (e.g. input of the form `[a[b[c]]]`), then you need something other than regex (this is one reason why trying to use regex to parse HTML doesn't work).

Comment: You don't actually need to escape the `]` in the character class, if you really want to be evil :)

Answer (score 1):

Your regex `[Blah(?:\s*)\]` starts with an unescaped '[' which is "seen" as the start of a character class. That's what's wrong with your regex (there are probably more errors, but that one is the main reason).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to `\[Blah[^\]]*\]` or `\[Blah.*?\]`. They should give the same result, but there might be a difference in their performance.